# How to make du command throw input/output error

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive, du

How to make `du` command throw `input/output error`. For some reason, I want to reproduce this use case and want to verify my fix before changes pushed to production. I am not able to understand how to reproduce this use case. I tried so many thing, but no luck. Any other command also fine which throws input/output error for file system.

E.g.

```
du -sh /data/
du: cannot access '/data/': Input/output error
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message [appears to be EIO](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/7b1cfba79ee54221ffa7d7879433b7ee1728cd76/sysdeps/gnu/errlist.h#L34). The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) says

> ```
> EIO    Input/output error (POSIX.1-2001).
> ```

In-turn, [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html):

> Input/output error. Some physical input or output error has occurred. This error may be reported on a subsequent operation on the same file descriptor. Any other error-causing operation on the same file descriptor may cause the [EIO] error indication to be lost.

So, where does that leave you? Well, you need to somehow simulate du receiving EIO from a syscall. You should be able to [use strace to make an arbitrary syscall return EIO](https://medium.com/@manav503/using-strace-to-perform-fault-injection-in-system-calls-fcb859940895), but which one?

Start by running `du` under strace to see which syscalls might return EIO. fstat(2) does not return EIO on Linux, so it must be another syscall.

Comment: Just because it's not in the man page, doesn't mean `du` won't propagate it. This worked for me: `strace -o /dev/null -e inject=fstat:when=4:error=EIO du /home`. Also, I didn't know strace can inject errors, thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks Sagar and root. Will try this command.